# How to deploy symfony 2 app

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I am new to symphony2 and I need to know how can I make my application run without the server:run commmand. What do I need to do to be able to make it run inside the root folder of my nginx server on port 80?

Comment: Symfony doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html and text: `The server:run command is only suitable while developing the application. In order to run Symfony applications on production servers, you'll have to configure your **Apache or Nginx web server as explained in Configuring a Web Server**.

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are several steps you need to do.**
1. Install Apache or similar web server on your hosting server.
2. Create a virtual host which points to the directory where your Symfony app is.
3. Allow proper permissions to folders.
4. Run your web server from specific console command.

Refer following two URLs for more details:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Point it to the web folder.